# How to know which file(file name) is transfered through FTP/SFTP

Tags: linux, ftp, log-files, sftp

Think of a situation I transferred a file through FTP, in which log I can find the name of the file transferred. Kindly mention the location of the log file.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Please edit with info on what ftp client you are using.

Comment: We cannot tell you what you did without sufficient detailed information about the tools you used. In general : servers only log detailed information if they are configured to do so (and you can’t travel into the past to change the log level to start collecting details you need because you now need them) and the same for clients,  usually they don’t maintain transfer logs although they can be configured to do (but not AFTER the fact)

Comment: No. No. No, whatever transfer protocol is used, I just told FTP as an example. i want to know if the file transferred through ftp. is it possible to check that particular file name in any of the log files in the server? Not in the client software used.

Answer (score 0):

That depends if you used a commandline client or a gui client.

The commandline client is easy, the standard way is to provide a `-v|--verbose` flag to enable showing filenames when copied, or read the `man` page for said cli client. You can save this output to stdout by piping the command `ftp -v folder remote.com:21 > log.txt` notice the `> log.txt` at the end.

If it's a gui it's up to you to find the checkbox to enable logging, or read the manual where/if it describes logging.

**Btw, you never mentioned what client, this is essential to give you the answer.**

Comment: No. No. No, whatever transfer protocol is used, I just told FTP as an example. i want to know if the file transferred through ftp. is it possible to check that particular file name in any of the log files in the server? Not in the client software used.